# EXCEL VB take me to the very bottom of my excel

Tags: vba, excel

This is the first time I'm working with Macros. I've created a dropdown in "A52" and "A122" with a "BLACK" and "WHITE" options.

If A52 is selected "WHITE", Row 59-61 Hides
If A52 is selected "BLACK", Row 56-58 Hides
Vice Versa if chosen on A122.

The only problem is the cursor and a excel view take me to row 126-127 everytime drop down is chosen. It did hide corresponding rows, just take me to the bottom everytime.

Any tips and tricks are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("A52") = "WHITE" Then
    Rows("59:61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Rows("59:61").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("A52") = "BLACK" Then
    Rows("56:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Rows("56:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("A122") = "WHITE" Then
    Rows("124:125").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Rows("124:125").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("A122") = "BLACK" Then
    Rows("126:127").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Rows("126:127").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't replicate this personally - but you can always drop in something like `Range("A1").Activate` or `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1` if your tests trigger.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem, but I did use a slightly different event, "Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)". Your code seemed to work fine for me, the cursor remained on the cell with the dropdown. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I run your macro and cursor remains on the cell I selected. Are you sure there are not more lines of code in your macro?